# elastic parallelism and fault-tolerance in distributed Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, fault-tolerance

How does Julia expose fault-tolerance - when a node goes down (intentionally or not) and when communication between nodes goes down.

I saw a [few mentions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/217) of such a feature but could not find out exactly how it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pmap docstrings you can see that this has already been implemented there using the `retry_` keyword arguments.

```
pmap([::AbstractWorkerPool], f, c...; distributed=true, batch_size=1,
on_error=nothing, retry_n=0, retry_max_delay=DEFAULT_RETRY_MAX_DELAY,
retry_on=DEFAULT_RETRY_ON) -> collection
```

> ... Any error stops pmap from processing the remainder of
>   the collection. To override this behavior you can specify an error
>   handling function via argument on_error which takes in a single
>   argument, i.e., the exception. The function can stop the processing by
>   rethrowing the error, or, to continue, return any value which is then
>   returned inline with the results to the caller.
>
> Failed computation can
>   also be retried via retry_on, retry_n, retry_max_delay, which are
>   passed through to retry as arguments retry_on, n and max_delay
>   respectively. If batching is specified, and an entire batch fails, all
>   items in the batch are retried.

I don't think there's anything like this for the @parallel macro. But you can use the `Base.wrap_on_error` & `Base.wrap_retry` functions to extend your original function to deal with errors. You can see much of the implementation details by looking through the definition of `pmap` at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v0.5.0/base/pmap.jl.

The basic strategy is just to catch the error (and potentially the data) and retry using the same worker, or another if that one is down. I think.